# Applying Change of Coordinates/variables - How do I find the jacobian and change the integration interval

Tags: change-of-variable, jacobian

> Employ change of variables $u=x-y$, $v=x+y$ to evaluate the 2-dimensional integral: $\int \int (x-y)e^{x^2-y^2} dxdy$. This represents region R. R is the region bounded by the lines $x+y=1$ and $x+y=3$ and the curves $x^2 -y^2 =1$ and $x^2 - y^2 = -1$

I understand that there are 3 steps to changing the coordinates:

The first step, I substituted the new variable into the integrad :

$(x-y) e^{x^2 - y^2} = ue^{uv}$

Next, I need to know how to find the Jacobian:

$J(x,y,u,v) = \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$

I have a problem with identifying what is the expression of $x$ and $y$ in order to do the partial differentiation for $u$ and $v$,

Next, is to find the new integration limits for $u$ and $v$, how do I go about finding that with this complicated region without a graphical calculator?

I've graphed it out on a graphical calculator and both $x$ and $y$ falls is in the region $ 0 \le x/y \le 1.667$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the **new region** from the transformation we'll need to **apply the change of variables to whatever the region $R$ is** in your question. For example, for some sort of triangle we might translate the vertices of that shape. I don't think I can help you more without seeing what the region $R$ referred to is.

To identify the expressions for your partial differentiation, try rearranging your two transformation equations and perhaps use elimination to find an equation in the form you want. For example:
$$u=x-y, v=x+y$$
$$\implies{u+v=2x}$$
$$\implies{x=\frac{u+v}{2}}$$

$$\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Hopefully this helps finding the jacobian!

Comment: https://www.math.utah.edu/lectures/math2210/25PostNotes.pdf
sorry also just found these lecture notes with some nice similar worked examples!

Comment: thank you! I've forgotten to indicate the region R. I've edited

Comment: Great, you should be able to just transform that region defined by the equations to the $u,v$ plane, giving your new integration region.

Comment: how does the Region R bounded by those 4 functions allow me to find the new integration limits of the new variables $u$ and $v$?

Comment: We can use the change of variable equations to put our bounding equations in terms of $u$ and $v$. For example:
$$x+y=1{\implies}v=1$$
$$x+y=3{\implies}v=3$$
$$x^2-y^2=1{\implies}uv=1$$
$$x^2-y^2=-1{\implies}uv=-1$$
We then have a new region in the $u,v$ plane using these transformed equations!   

From this new region we can see the $v$ limits are from 1 to 3, and the $u$ limits are -1 to 1.